# write to stdin of mintty using ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh, file-descriptor, mintty

I try to start a mintty instance (running ssh) with a ruby script. When ssh asks for the password i would like to enter the password with the script. I've tried the following:

```
f = IO.popen("C:/.../cygwin/bin/mintty.exe /usr/bin/ssh user@host", 'r+')
f.puts "password\n"
f.close
```

When i execute this code ssh is started in a new mintty window. but the `password` is not recognized. I am not even sure if it reaches the STDIN of this process. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try running that command from the command line and experimenting?  Does Windows have something like `echo foo | command` or `command < filename` in Unix?

Comment: Windows itself does not have this ability. In mintty I can run `echo foo | ssh -t -t user@host`. But in this case foo is not piped to the password prompt. It is piped to the ssh session. That mena s I will get something like this after login: `user@host $ foo`